# Saving the opened file in particular folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist and a textbox. When i write some name and select some options in dropdownlist like word or excel or powerpoint, that particular file opens as an attachment and i should save it in "data" folder which is already present in the solution explorer. My code is like this

```
string file = TextBox1.Text;
        if (dd1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/word";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename =" + file + ".docx");
        }
```

How can I store this file in "data" folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is "you cannot".  Saving file is taking place on the client side.  Your web application knows nothing about the client machine (not even whether it's a real browser or another script) and has no control over the client.  The end user will have to manually select `data` folder to save the file to.

Comment: Or is there any other method to open these files and store in "data" folder?

Comment: I have user Interipop but still not able to store. My code goes like this

Comment: There is no way at all, whatsoever, to control anything that happens on the user's machine from your web application.  From the point of your web application, the user's machine does not exist.  Your app knows nothing about the user's machine, it's operating system, browser or directory structure.